# emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored. in jenkins in Ubuntu

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, continuous-integration, ubuntu-16.04

Trying to Android Emulator Plugin in Jenkins 2.38.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.
Getting following error:

WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
[android] Stopping Android emulator

Please help